# Using SQL Commands to subtract 1 minute intervals from Date Column to return matched record

Tags: sql, function, if-statement, while-loop

I have a database and within this DB I have a Table called "Bakery".  Within this Table there are two columns, Food and Time.  The first column Food represents the food that is produce and then the second column Time represnts the time the food it was made.
Example

```
FOOD        TIME
Cookie      5:00 AM  
Cookie      5:10 AM  
Cookie      5:18 AM  
Cookie      5:30 AM
```

If I want to create a SQL Command to see when the last batch of food was made to when a customer purchased a Food what would be the best way to do this.

Example

> John bought a cookie at 5:17 AM when was the last batch of cookies made for John?

I want the result to return 5:10 AM.

And I have hundreds of Names and different foods so what would be the best way?

Comment: You most certainly don't need to use any loops, if-statements, or decrements of time at all.  What DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.) are you using?

Comment: You need `MAX` time among those that less than "John's" time).

Comment: Just order by datetime descending and select the first record with a datetime < 5:17AM

Comment: Your query should look something like this (query may vary for DBMS): `SELECT MAX(TIME) FROM Bakery WHERE TIME < @InputTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "input" values are `BUYED_FOOD` (*cookie* i.e.) and `TIME_OF_BUYING` (*5:17* i.e.).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (FOOD) * 
FROM Bakery
WHERE 
   FOOD = 'cookie' AND 
   TIME < TIME_OF_BUYING
ORDER BY FOOD, TIME DESC
```

This example is general and returns whole row from `Bakery`. If you want to return only `TIME` you can replace `DISTINCT` part and `ORDER .. DESC` with `MAX(TIME)` like so :

```
SELECT MAX(TIME) 
FROM Bakery
WHERE 
   FOOD = 'cookie' AND 
   TIME < TIME_OF_BUYING
```

Comment: What if I only want it to return the one record and not all the records?

Comment: `DISTINCT` makes query returns only one rowfor each `FOOD` from whole bunch that normally query will return only with `WHERE` clause; in this case it works with `WHERE` part that shows only one - *cookie* - row.